# Mongodb collection name changed after creation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Problem is that then I run this code, after I check the db records with Robomongo on windows, I see only one collection created with name 'maximas' with two records, 
if I remove Model2 from code, after creation result will be the same, but must be collection 'maxima'.

*Is there bug in code that i don't see, or this word is reserved, any ideas?*

**The code,**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mymodels', (e)=>{
if(e) throw e;
});

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
text: {type: String}
});

var Model1 = mongoose.model('maxima', schema);

var Model2 = mongoose.model('maximas', schema);

var newData1 = new Model1({
text: 'test'
});

var newData2 = new Model2({
text: 'test'
});

newData1.save((e)=>{
if(e) throw e;
console.log('Saved');
});


newData2.save((e)=>{
if(e) throw e;
console.log('Saved');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose will automatically pluralise your model name as the collection name. This is why they are both the same, as the second collection name is already in plural form.

You can pass the desired collection name as the third model argument:

```
var Model1 = mongoose.model('maxima', schema, 'maxima');

var Model2 = mongoose.model('maximas', schema, 'maximas');
```

NOTE: You can also specify your collection name as an option in your schema:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: { type: String }
}, {
    collection: 'maxima'
});
```

...but in this case you would require a second schema so the first approach above is more suitable here.

Comment: Yes you are right, I found that Mongoose is trying to be smart. You can however force it to be whatever you want:
var dataSchema = new Schema({..}, { collection: 'data' }) ,

Comment: Glad this helped you